# Accessing a string using counter variable in C/C++

Tags: c, string, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

In a C++ reference book, I found an example that accessed a string like following:

```
void main()
{
    char *str = "Test";
    int len, i;

    clrscr();

    len = strlen(str);
    for(i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", i[str]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Why does `i[str]` work? `i` is a variable, not an array.

It also works if the string is declared as `str[]` instead of `*str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Char pointers point to the memory location at the start of a string, and the array indexes (eg, `str[i]`) are basically adding `i` iterations to the start of the string.

So, `str + i` = `str[i]` = `i[str]` = `i + str`

Using this inside `printf`, like you are doing, all of these will evaluate the same:

```
printf("%c", str[i]);
printf("%c", i[str]);
printf("%c", *(str+i));
printf("%c", *(i+str));
```

See also: [With arrays, why is it the case that a[5] == 5[a]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

Comment: Great, this explains it. So as I understand it, since the compiler knows that out of i and str, str is the pointer. So the memory area str points to are supposed to be accessed and not of i, even if we write i outside the brackets?

Comment: yes.  the compiler is essentially adding the two numbers, and either way you add them you get to the same place

Answer (score 0):

It works because in C `i[str]` and `str[i]` are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

`i[str]` and `str[i]` evaluate the same way (as `*(str+i)` )

When you declare `str[]`, `str` is a pointer to the first element of the array

Comment: Okay to generalize it, we can say that constant[pointer] and pointer[constant] are same? Because liberal understanding would say that str means some hex value of a memory address, which will mean i[str] is actually constant[0x123213] ... ???